# Design a help screen for OS X application

Tags: xcode, macos

I want to design a custom help screen for my app. I wanted to model it based on the help screen for the native Mac apps like mail and safari.

[image]

Notice the similarities to SplitViewController on iOS. However some categories in the sidebar also have the ability to expand into subcategories like 'Send email'.

What UI control could be used to design something like this?

(I need to support 10.10 and above)

Comment: Have you looked at using the [default help system](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/user_help_intro/user_assistance_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903)?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes but I am planning to have a lot more features than default system.

Comment: Use NSOutlineView for the left view and a custom NSView for the right view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSOutlineView seems like the best fit, as pointed out by rocky.